# битовая маска mysql

Tags: mysql

подскажите у меня есть таблица в ней числа, мне надо перенести с этой таблицы в другую 2 значения с битовой маской? непонимаю я в них? с примера 2 числа 1067254670,1609105408

есть кусок ява кода в котором я проверяю значения

```
  java public static int getVariationId1(int augmentMask)
    {
        final int mask = 0b1111111111111111;
        return mask & augmentMask;
    }

    public static int getVariationId2(int augmentMask)
    {
        final int mask = 0b1111111111111111;
        return mask & augmentMask >>> 16;

    }

910 (1067254670-число)
16285 (1067254670-число)
0 (1609105408-число)
24553 (1609105408-число) 

как сделать тоже самое через запрос mysql?
```

Comment: непонимаю, дайте пример с числом например тем что я дал

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL: Операторы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)

```
mysql> SELECT 1067254670 & b'1111111111111111' val1,
    -> (1067254670 >> 16) & b'11111111111111111' val2,
    -> 1609105408 & b'11111111111111111' val3,
    -> (1609105408 >> 16) & b'11111111111111111' val4;
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| val1 | val2  | val3  | val4  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  910 | 16285 | 65536 | 24553 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Обрезку в нужное количество битов выполнять с помощью оператора AND либо (для ровно 1-2-3-4-8 байтов) с помощью CAST к соотв. типу.

Также всё то же можно выполнить и арифметическими операторами.

```
mysql> SELECT 1067254670 MOD 65536 val1,
    -> 1067254670 DIV 65536 val2,
    -> 1609105408 MOD 65536 val3,
    -> 1609105408 DIV 65536 val4;
+------+-------+------+-------+
| val1 | val2  | val3 | val4  |
+------+-------+------+-------+
|  910 | 16285 |    0 | 24553 |
+------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Тут даже старшие биты занулять не придётся.

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться